# How do I make the AlertDialog box appear outside the app?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-alarms

```
@Override
public void run() {
    //Create thread that can alter the UI
    AlarmPage.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            //See if current time matches set alarm time
            if((cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == alarmTime.getCurrentHour()) 
                    && (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == alarmTime.getCurrentMinute())){
                //If the sound is playing, stop it and rewind
                if(sound.isPlaying()){
                    ShowDialog();
                    alarmTimer.cancel();
                    alarmTask.cancel();
                    alarmTask = new PlaySoundTask();
                    alarmTimer = new Timer();
                    alarmTimer.schedule(alarmTask, sound.getDuration(), sound.getDuration());
                }
                sound.start();
            }       
        }
    });
}

public void ShowDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("REMINDER!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Turn off alarm by pressing off");

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Off", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I am making a simple alarm clock app that notifies the user. I want to make a alert box that gives the user the option to turn off the alarm when it goes off. I was able to make the alert box, but it only appears in the app not outside of the app. I understand the app has to be in the background running. If I need to show more code or be more specific, just ask please.

Comment: You should use notification to alert the user when app is not in foreground.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081380/how-to-create-alertdialog-outside-of-an-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line as:

```
public void ShowDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("REMINDER!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Turn off alarm by pressing off");

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Off", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
    // line you have to add
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
}
```

check now.

Comment: Please try to let the questioner know where this code is supposed to be inserted, and also provide some commentary on what this code is doing and why.

Comment: I know where to put it, problem is that getWindow() isn't working, "Cannot resolve".

Comment: @Ravi Koradiya i changed some stuff and it works, problem is it doesn't show it outside of the code, got any ideas?

Comment: getWindow doesn't exist. please explain your solution also

Answer (score 1):

Do not accept answers if they don't address your question, it is misleading.

The accepted answer is not correct, as it will never work outside your application.

Reason:

1. It requires an activity context not application context.
2. If you provide application context, your app will crash with **IllegalArgumentException- you need to use Theme.AppCompat or their decendents...**

If you need functionality as actually stated in the question you have to have a separate activity themed as a Dialog like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081614/3024565)

or you can add a custom view to your window using window manager and making it system level alert like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21182403/3024565).

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Do this create an `Activity` without `ContentView` or a `View` associated with it and call your `alertDialog` method in your `onCreate` also remember to set the background of the `Activity` to `Transparent` using `ColourDrawable`

And that activity will look like a dialog or will suit your preference, you can also fall back to `Theme`s so you can set an `Activity` as `Dialog` and treat it like `Dialog` also use `DialogFragment`